# Javascript action based on multiple possible DIV contents

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide, contains

I need help writing a javascript filter for a page that is changing depending on city and state.  The state options are provided as a single select dropdown and the cities are presented as checkboxes (i.e. multiple cities can be selected).  All DIVs (parent DIV containing one city DIV and one state DIV) contain the city and state name in their respective DIVs like this:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='state'>Alabama</div>
  <div class='city'>Anniston</div>
</div>
```

These are initially loaded on the page and then hidden based on the initial filter (state='AL' city='all').  When the user changes the filter either by selecting a new state or checking/unchecking a city, it triggers a javascript function that re-evaluates which DIVs are hidden and which are shown.

The state filter works great using:

```
$(".parent").hide();
$(".state:contains('" + state + "')").parent().show();
```

to display all the parent DIVs that match the state passed to the function.  I am having problems with the city select.  I want the user to be able to select multiple cities so I need some way to show all the parent DIVs where the city DIV matches any of the selected cities AND still match the state also.  I am starting by hiding all DIVs, then showing the matching states, then trying to hide the non-matching cities. Something like:

```
$(".parent").hide();
$(".state:contains('" + state + "')").parent().show();
$(".city:not(:contains('" + [city1 OR city2 OR city3 OR ...] + "'))").parent().hide();
```

Obviously the [city1 OR city2 OR city3 OR ...] part doesn't work.  Any suggestions on how to get this working with multiple inputs like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()` mmethod

I'm not sure how your checkboxes are set up so will pseudo code them

First create array of all the cities:

```
var cities=$('.cityCheckBox:checked').map(function(){
  return this.value
}).get();
```

Now filter the city elements based on text not being in the array

```
$(".parent").show();
$('.city').filter(function(){
   var city=$.trim($(this).text());
   /* return only cities not in array*/
   return $.inArray( city,cities) == -1;
}).parent().hide();
```

This assumes you are only filtering by city. For filter both city and state would just need a bit more robust test in the filter function. Not 100% clear what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you!  I already had an array of the checked cities so I didn't test that part but the filter function worked perfectly!